# How to store user settings (username, password) in a Windows application for the current logged in user

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Now my team is working on a project involving a Windows application (C#).

The application has a option for saving the username and password in the client machine for the current logged in user. The user can start the application without entering username and password. Please check the snapshot of my requirement.

Please suggest a good example or reference.

[Alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0ff58473e0.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/0ff58473e0.jpg)

Comment: When the user click checkbox with a label "Remember me".The application must store username & password in the client machine for the current login user.so the same user can start the application with out giving username & password again

Comment: The simple [solution suggested by Bus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681580/how-to-store-user-settings-username-password-in-a-windows-application-for-the/2681748#2681748) with encryption on the password may have some value.

Comment: you got the solution? I am looking for a similar stuff. ;)

Answer (score 20):

To persist user credentials easily and in a secure way you can write them to the application configuration file using the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=VS.80).aspx) class, secure the password using the [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) class and then encrypt it using tools in the Cryptography namespace.

Edit: This might help: [Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx)

Comment: +1 for securing and encrypting it
Never store the password as a clear string.

Comment: i know this is pretty old but i have the same problem with a question. if i store the username and password on app.config i cannot change it on runtime because the application is stored under program files , and there could be access problems to the file... how can i store a username and password localy with the ability to change it on runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class [you can download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/203578/UserCredentialsDialog.zip) and possibly use.  It uses the windows Credential API and provides a dialog, much like the credential dialog in windows, that allows you to save credentials.

It was a proof of concept I did, but it was never need in a production application.  So use at your own risk :)

Comment: I think this class will be *very* similar to the code you'll find in the link @ho posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple solution, saving the user name and password in user settings would work. However, this approach is not very secure at all because any other user with sufficient privileges on this machine could simply read the saved settings and steal your login details.