# What's the best way to store a password to acces/change it on runtime on winforms application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, passwords, store, updates

The password is needed to complete the database connectionstring. The password is changed each month. I want to detect when the password is changed and ask the user for the new password and store it for next executions.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of database will the app be accessing? An external database on a remote server? Or something locale?

Comment: db2/sql external database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your password in application configuration file using the ConfigurationManager class, secure the password using the SecureString class and then encrypt it using tools in the Cryptography namespace.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681580/how-to-store-user-settings-username-password-in-a-windows-application-for-the)

Comment: Can I change it on runtime? It will remain updated for next executions?

Comment: Yes you can ......... [Check This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That's what i want. Thank you!