# How to read and write custom sections in app.config?

Tags: c#, vb.net, app-config

I want to read and write the users settings in the app.config file of my project.
I want to add the user name as a section and adding its setting, for each user if he is not exist in the app.config.
And I want to read it at the beginning of the application.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681580/how-to-store-user-settings-username-password-in-a-windows-application-for-the

Comment: It's worth noting that this would be a pretty terrible way to store data.  In order for changes to the web.config to be recognized, the AppDomain has to be restarted.  This would have a very disruptive effect on your users' experience, not to mention cause performance problems.  You should either use a proper database or flat file to store this information.

Answer (score 0):

.Net already has this class `ConfigurationManager` you can use to read app.config and web.config for web scenarios. You could use something like this

```
var temp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["data"];
```

for more info please check the MSDN [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)